# How to develop an OpenCL application targeting specifically Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 (UHD Graphics 630) without this device?

Tags: opencl, emulation, intel, device-emulation

I've been tasked to develop an OpenCL application for a specific platform, Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 (UHD Graphics 630). There are two problems for me:

- Even having some OpenCL programming experience (not that much though), I wouldn't know where to begin. I have no prior experience with targeting specific hardware before.
- The device itself has to be emulated or something, because I don't have it at hand.

Of course, I tried googling information today, but couldn't find anything that could really help me. Guess, it's just because of my lack of experience. So, I'm stumped right now, and asking for help.

It would be really great if I can be helped. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Small note: I'm working on this project under Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Why didn't you just tell your boss that you aren't a wizard? If you are too successful with this task you will never get further education or so - you will always get "impossible" tasks in the future.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Well, you're right in the general case, but actually this depends on the individual situation. I mean, I have my reasons to work on this project, and also, I'm expecting that several of my next projects will be similar to this one, so I'm suffering from the lack of experience only for now, while completion of this task would give me enough experience for future ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any emulated environment, and anyway, ultimately nothing replaces access to the target hardware. I see a few workarounds:

- Target a similar-enough device. Intel GPUs haven't changed that drastically, so especially if you have an older/lower-spec one around, whatever you end up with should run *better* on the newer GPU. You can also work with a GPU from another vendor if you have at least sporadic access to a system with an Intel GPU. You don't want to go for too long at a time without testing on your target hardware. (It's generally a good idea to test OpenCL code against different implementations while developing, as it's easy to accidentally rely on implementation-defined or undefined behaviour otherwise.)
- Rent a relevant physical device. Places exist that allow you to rent laptops or desktop PCs for a short time period.
- Remote access to a target device. Presumably whoever posed the requirement *actually has such devices*. Ask for remote access to one of them, via *the magic of the internet*. (RDP, VNC, SSH)
- Rent similar hardware in a data centre. There are bare metal hosting companies that rent out physical servers built from commodity hardware. Find one that offers servers with a close enough match to the system you're targeting and rent one there.

As for the skill gap, well, you'll either have to bridge that one yourself by following enough documentation, tutorials, etc. or by finding (hiring…) someone who will give you some degree of hand-holding through the project.

Comment: Note that the Xeons in typical servers don't have integrated graphics, at least not enabled.  You really do need bare metal of a Xeon-W (aimed at workstations) or a "client" CPU (i3/i5/i7).  Or for Coffee Lake, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xeon#Coffee_Lake-based_Xeon shows a table of Xeons including [E2-288G](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/193743/intel-xeon-e2288g-processor-16m-cache-3-70-ghz.html) with P630 graphics.  https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/graphics/126790/intel-uhd-graphics-630.html shows Intel CPUs with UHD 630 graphics

Comment: @PeterCordes Your overall point is correct, but I think you mean the *Xeon-**E*** series contains the same iGPU as the desktop/laptop processors. In any case you need to look at the specs of the system exactly and look up the iGPU based on the precise CPU model number.